# Pulsating colors in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I'd like to have some text pulsate between red and black.  Figured I'd use [jQuery UI's animate function](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) to do so.  Seems simple enough... something like:

```
function pulseRed() {
    $('.pulsing').animate({ color: "red" }, 1000, pulseBlack);
}
function pulseBlack() {
    $('.pulsing').animate({ color: "black" }, 1000, pulseRed);
});
```

My concern is how efficient this is.  If I have a lot of text in different places to pulsate, should I instead somehow alter the CSS stylesheet rule for `.pulsing`?  Is it safe to have an infinite loop between functions like that or am I going to get in trouble for stacking too many function calls?

I'm already using jQuery and jQuery UI, so I don't mind at all using the animate color mechanism above... but if there's a better solution I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Is this a `<blink>` web 2.0 tag? Say it ain't so!

Comment: I know you've got a bunch of questions, but you should consider going through them and trying to select some more answers.

Comment: @ByronWhitlock - It could be for an HTML5 game. Give the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Byron, I promise my design with this pulsating text is tasteful :)
@Moshe, I sometimes don't really get any good answers, but I will go back and review this

Comment: @at, concerning your second question, you don't really need to worry about the stack because callbacks are not recursive calls. What happens is that you start the loop by calling, say, `pulseRed()`, which calls `animate()`, which queues the animation and *immediately returns*. So, `pulseRed()` will also return, and your stack is clean. `pulseBlack()` will be called later by the jQuery queuing mechanism, and its call to `animate()` will follow the same principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery UI you might want to consider using the [animated toggle class](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/) instead, if you wrapped that in a setInterval() function you could reduce it to one line, and store the formatting in the CSS rather than the javascript.

Comment: That seems more efficient to toggle a CSS class rather than the potentially hundreds of pieces of text individually.  Though it's quite possible jQuery and jQuery UI implement this the same underneath anyway.  This toggleClass effect doesn't have a completion callback method, so how do I know when to start the toggle back to the original color?  Just setInterval for the same time duration?  Could that cause issues with slightly off timings?

Comment: Yes it could, I suppose you would have to do some trial and error to get the timings correct. The other option is to use the jquery timers plugin which may provide more control.

The problem with call backs on the same function (I think not entirely sure) is it could cause too much recursion and slow the script down. Don't hold me to that though.